# Is it appropriate to broadly push for domain clarification?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

While there are a lot of general Project Management aspects that apply across domains, there are also many questions and answers that depend heavily on the domain. For example, the constraints and concerns in software project management are somewhat different than those managing marking projects, and very different than construction projects or pure research projects.

Should we add a guideline into the FAQ to include this for good questions, and provide a broad push through comments to ensure specifics are provided in the questions when they could be relevant?

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ](https://pm.stackexchange.com/faq) currently outlines what's on topic, and it also directs users to [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), which describes the six guidelines for good subjective questions.

In addition, [Tips for Writing Great Questions](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77/tips-for-writing-great-questions) has some great suggestions for getting the most out of your questions and ensure that you get the answers you're looking for.

We do encourage question-askers to provide detail that supports the question in comments, and adding this to the FAQ may be helpful.

Keep in mind that it's not always clear what details are important when you, the question asker, knows all the details; therefore, asking for clarification is just a normal part of the process.

Answer (score 1):

In the short term, I'd just make sure you're gently reminding users to provide enough context for their questions.

In the longer term, those sorts of things will feed back into the /faq and the dynamic advice for new users on answer, the sidebar help for askers, etc.