# Is my question a bad fit for PM.SE?

Tags: support, site-topic

Given the amount of views, lack-of-comments, lack-of-votes -- is the following question a bad fit for the PM.SE site: [Business Requirements Analysis for Business Intelligence](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/business-requirements-analysis-for-business-intelligence), and if so, why?

Also, is there a SE site that would be a better fit? An example of another site that might be a fit is [DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Give it a little more time. It looks like it was asked around 10 pm Eastern time, U.S.  and it is only 10 am now.

Comment: +1 @Mark Phillips: Okay, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: now there are 3 answers

Comment: +1 @mhoran_psprep: So, do you think I should just delete this question?  I don't see the point in leaving it as a question without an answer. If you wanted to post you comment that there are now three answers, and that it appears posting this question was of use, or that  Mark Phillips appears to have been right, that my reading of the lack of response was unfounded. Thanks!

Comment: Here are some more tips that I think are helpful http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info:doi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally looked at your question when you first posted it. I thought you had some good detail, but at the time my brain was slightly on overload after a long day.  All of your content was squished together in one big paragraph. We're human beings, and sometimes the way something is written can have a huge impact on how the community interprets and responds to your question.

**Below are some tools to put in your toolbox for writing great, attractive questions:**

**Use Whitespace**

Since you have a lot of detail, you may want to consider editing your question body, using bullet points to highlight critical information. Breaking the details up into different paragraphs, instead of one long paragraph, is also helpful.

**Write a Catchy Title**

The title of your question can have a lot of impact on the amount of views you receive. For instance, consider the following two questions:

- [How Can I Obtain a Project Management Position With No Professional Experience In The Field?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/4832/34) *This was asked on our site less than a week ago, and it's already received 3,000 pageviews*!
- [How to Avoid Micro-Managing a Software Development Team?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/452/34).

Notice how both questions, in one sentence, make it very clear what the problem is. They're catchy, interesting, and draw us in so that we click on the question to learn more about your specific problem.

When I look at your question title, it says *"Business Requirements Analysis for Business Intelligence"*, which tells me nothing about the specific problem or challenge that you're facing. It's not very catchy. Consider rewriting your title so that it asks what you are looking for.

> What is the best way to discover, prioritize, and iteratively deploy business intelligence solutions?

This is what you wrote as the first sentence in the question body. Why not use this as your post title? It has many of the qualities as in the two examples I posted.

**More Resources**

Check out our [Tips For Writing Great Questions](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/77/34), which will help you get the most out of your question, as the best questions give rise to the best answers.

**Also, anyone in our community can help question-askers ask great questions by leaving comments, or editing the question directly to help improve it. The better the quality of the content on this Q&A beta site, the better our chances of attracting more great users!**

Comment: +1 RELATED: [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) -- Main issue I have with your edit as it stands now is if the question is being viewed from within a listing of other questions, it will read: "**What is the best way to discover, prioritize, and iteratively deploy business intelligence solutions?** What is the best way to discover, prioritize, and iteratively deploy business intelligence solutions?", since when you edited the title, you left the question on the first line.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guess to be honest, I just posted this question to boost my question, or at least see if it would. That said, currently the answer I found after posting the question to me seems like the best answer -- that being the book by Lawrence Corr titled [Agile Data Warehouse Design](http://books.google.com/books?id=TRWFmnv8jP0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Agile-Data-Warehouse-Design-Collaborative&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nBVOT57dMKT50gG9nu3RAg&ved=0CEsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Agile-Data-Warehouse-Design-Collaborative&f=false).

Comment: I'm glad you asked this meta question though because it may help remind us all what to think about when we post questions.  Also, in regards to my edits on your question, please, please feel free to continue to improve it. Our goal is to not just answer your question, but to create great content that will serve others for years to come :)

Comment: Guess the only thing I might add is that based on my experience that while I also like whitespace/bulletpoint/etc -- oddly those questions based on my experiences on SE of asking 100s of questions (5-10% of which I delete before an answer is found, or based on feedback)... block-text, paragraph-style questions tend to do better, though clearly I've never done any quantitative analysis on this.

Comment: It's also okay to leave a question that isn't getting answers. Sometimes it takes the community awhile to respond. There are some examples of questions here, on StackOverflow, etc that don't have a single answer. Again, while we do hope *you* get great answers, we also hope the content here will be found by people searching on Google for years to come.

Answer (score 1):

You now have 4 people who have submitted answers to your question. It would be nice for you to vote for one of them

Comment: +1 @mhoran_psprep: Thanks, though guess you're answer here is different than the comment above, so I'll attempt to address the part of your answer that's directed towards voting on the answers. I have reviewed all of the answers, and to my knowledge all address general business requirements gathering, not "Business Requirements Analysis for Business Intelligence", which to me is not the same thing.

Comment: If the 4 answers are not appropriate then edit your question to make it clear what you are looking for. Analysis of Business data is not much different from other forms of data analysis.

Comment: +1 @mhoran_psprep: Done. If you have additional feedback as a result of the updates, or any questions, let me know. Thanks!